# Flutter web upload file

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I want to upload files using Flutter web, but I encountered some problems, my steps are as follows:

```dart
/// choose file
  void _chooseFile() {
    InputElement uploadInput = FileUploadInputElement();
    uploadInput.accept = ".mp4";
    uploadInput.multiple = true;
    uploadInput.click();
    uploadInput.onChange.listen((event) {
      final files = uploadInput.files;
      if (files.length == 1) {
        final file = files[0];
        final reader = FileReader();
        reader.onLoadEnd.listen((event) {
          print('loaded: ${file.name}');
          print('type: ${reader.result.runtimeType}');
          print('file size = ${file.size}');
          _uploadFile(file);
        });
        reader.onError.listen((event) {
          print(event);
        });
        reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
      }
    });
  }

/// upload file
/// file: in dart:html package not in dart:io package
  void _uploadFile(File file) async {
    FormData data = FormData.fromMap({
      'file': MultipartFile.fromBytes(
        List<int>, // -----------------------------> problem line
        filename: file.name,
      )
    });
    Dio dio = new Dio();
    dio.post('upload file url', data: data, onSendProgress: (count, total) {
      print('$count ==> $total');
    }).then((value) {
      print('$value');
    }).catchError((error) => print('$error'));
  }
```

The problem is that  `MultipartFile.fromBytes(List<int> value, {...})`, but I don't know how to conver `file` **( in dart:html not in dart:io )** to `List<int>`.

Thanks!!!

Comment: What does `print('type: ${reader.result.runtimeType}');` print?

Comment: How did you solve this?

Answer (score 2):

You need to convert the `reader`, as below:

```
List<int> _selectedFile;
Uint8List _bytesData;

void _handleResult(Object result) {
    setState(() {
      _bytesData = Base64Decoder().convert(result.toString().split(",").last);
      _selectedFile = _bytesData;
    });
  }
```

call the func:

```
_handleResult(reader.result);
```

then, pass `_bytesData` to your  `MultipartFile.fromBytes(...)` or have return func type  as `List<int>` and call it anywhere you need.

For example, this is what I have done to get the image:

```
List<int> imageFileBytes;

    /// Browse Image:
  _setImage(int index) async {
    html.InputElement uploadInput = html.FileUploadInputElement();
    uploadInput.multiple = false;
    uploadInput.draggable = true;
    uploadInput.accept = 'image/*';
    uploadInput.click();
    html.document.body.append(uploadInput);
    uploadInput.onChange.listen((e) {
      final files = uploadInput.files;
      final file = files[0];
      final reader = new html.FileReader();
      reader.onLoadEnd.listen((e) {
        var _bytesData = Base64Decoder().convert(reader.result.toString().split(",").last);
        setState(() {
          imageFileBytes = _bytesData;
        });
      });
      reader.readAsDataUrl(file);
    });

    uploadInput.remove();
  }
```

Comment: I am trying to implement this solution and I get this error trying to decode as Base64String any file type:

loaded: source.gif
type: Uint8List
file size = 616456
Error: FormatException: Invalid character (at character 1)
 59]
^

Comment: I added an example that works for me. Get the parts you need to have  List<int>. @JasonPerfetto

Comment: Sorry for not following up but I was able to use this pattern successfully, but I had to adapt it to initialize my reader onLoadEnd listeners to happen in initState